# Can you make Asp.net MVC View wireup compile time safe?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, static-reflection

Take the standard return statement for a controller:

```
return View("Index");
```

is there a way to make this thing compile time safe? using [static reflection](http://jagregory.com/writings/introduction-to-static-reflection/) or some other trick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes; you're looking for [this](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc).

> T4MVC is a T4 template for ASP.NET MVC
>   apps that creates strongly typed
>   helpers that eliminate the use of
>   literal strings when referring to
>   controllers, actions and views. It
>   helps make your MVC code much more
>   maintainable, and gives you
>   intellisense where you normally would
>   not have any.

Comment: If this does what I think it does this is awesome.  I really hate all the literal strings and type unsafety that I've encountered since switching from .NET desktop applications to web application!!!

Comment: It generates a class hierarchy of string constants for action and controller names at compile-time using T4.

Comment: does it also include something for the weakly typed routeValueDictionary/object passing?

Comment: @Maslow since you can't tell what will be in a dictionary until run time, I don't see how this would be possible. Unit testing is your friend.

Comment: well, at least up to an int for `Id` the examples on the linked page do that. not sure why that's the only type he is doing strong typing on.

Comment: integrating this into an existing project I imagine is a bear =(

Comment: @AaronLs - turns out... integration was spectacularly easy.. except the bug I ran into where it wanted a Name property added to all controllers, and I had a Controller Action called `Name`